# Are there any meta tags equivalent to title / description that are less common in link previews but still relevant?

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-tags

Let's say you are making a page about yourself that you commonly share in communities where you are "anonymous", but you still want people who know you well to be able to find your page easily using your first- and lastname. Are there any tags that could help with SEO when you want to hide your last name from link previews but have it in said tag(s)?

Comment: You want your name to get indexed in search engines, but not appear in preview when shared on social meda?

Comment: What do you want to appear in preview on these communities?  Do you have a screen name that you would rather have show up?

Comment: As for your first question that's right. I want my full name to be indexed but only my first name should be shown in social previews, for the second question just my first name would be nice, as long as people who know my full name can still find my website online.